# Communication between directive function and transcluded controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that "manages" all the instances of the associated component. I would like the directive function to be able to call a function in the transcluded controller, and vice versa. An isolate scope in the link function does not provide this capability. Is this even possible in Angular 1.x? I have everything working, but only by using $broadcast() and hard-coding names into all the child controllers. It feels like a hack.

The directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        template: '...<ng-transclude />...',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            ...
        }
    };
});
```

And the transcluded content looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    ...
</div>
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to "inject" an object from the directive function into the transcluded controller that contains data and callbacks.